# beanparam with jersey-cdi-se fail to work

Tags: jersey, cdi, weld

when I'm using the beanparam together with jersey-cdi2-se jar
my code fail to work. I also tried it on your example:

https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/tree/master/examples/helloworld-cdi2-se
I added beanparam as a parameter to one of the controller and it didn't work.
when I remove the jersey-cdi-se dependency it's working.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In my case Jersey tried to look up the BeanParam class using the cdi framework and failed.

Annotating the Bean Class with @RequestScoped solved this issue for me, as it made the bean available for injection by the cdi framework.

I was using bean-discovery-mode="annotated" which made annotating all classes to be injected mandatory.